# How to read data from URL adjacent to localhost:8080/?data=test in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying fetch data from  URL (localhost:8080/?data=test) in node /express , but not able to catch in server.js file. But not sure why this is not catching in get('/') or get('*') method. This is the code I
am currently using.

```js
//Importing dependencies
const express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const port = process.env.PORT ||8081; 
//Starting Express app
const app = express();

//Set the base path to the angular-test dist folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/bybuy')));

//Any routes will be redirected to the angular app
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS",req.url);
    var str1="";
    if(req.query.data.indexOf(' ')>=0){
        var str1=replaceAll(req.query.data,' ','PLUS');
    }
        res.cookie('accessToken', str1,
    { 
      overwrite: true,
      encode: v => v
    })
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/bybuy/index.html'));
});


app.post('/home', function(req, res) {
    console.load("LKJHFDLKJDLKJDLKJD");
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/bybuy/index.html'));
    
    
});
app.post('/cashfreeResult',(req, res, next)=>{
    console.log("merchantHosted result hit");
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/bybuy/index.html'));
});

//Starting server on port 8081
;
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url);
    let parsedQs = querystring.parse(url_parts.query);
    console.log("NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO",parsedQs);
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/bybuy/index.html'));
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server started!');
    console.log('on port ',port);
})
function replaceAll(string, search, replace) {
  return string.split(search).join(replace);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

req.query
This property is an object containing a property for each query string parameter in the route. When query parser is set to disabled, it is an empty object {}, otherwise it is the result of the configured query parser.

As req.query’s shape is based on user-controlled input, all properties and values in this object are untrusted and should be validated before trusting. For example, req.query.foo.toString() may fail in multiple ways, for example foo may not be there or may not be a string, and toString may not be a function and instead a string or other user-input.

```
// GET /search?q=tobi+ferret
console.dir(req.query.q)
// => 'tobi ferret'

// GET /shoes?order=desc&shoe[color]=blue&shoe[type]=converse
console.dir(req.query.order)
// => 'desc'

console.dir(req.query.shoe.color)
// => 'blue'

console.dir(req.query.shoe.type)
// => 'converse'

// GET /shoes?color[]=blue&color[]=black&color[]=red
console.dir(req.query.color)
// => ['blue', 'black', 'red']
```

Check out the [document](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)

Comment: also check this https://evanhahn.com/gotchas-with-express-query-parsing-and-how-to-avoid-them/